# How to keep MongoDB same as the source? (laravel)

Tags: php, database, mongodb, laravel

I'm building a microservice. The microservice gets data through an API, and I want to save that data to my MongoDB. Then if the source does any updating, inserting, or deleting, I want MongoDB do so too.

Is it possible to do this in MongoDB? What query should I use?

Comment: What's 'source'? Is it another DB?

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev yea its mongodb too, but different machine

Comment: Ideally it should be Source responsibility to call a API to update this MongoDB.  Mongo to Mongo will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try replication on MongoDb?

I hope this can help your needs. Here  [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)